# npm ERR! code E404

Tags: hardhat, error

I am trying to run the hardhat commands such as npx hardhat or npx hardhat accounts but they only result in the same error:

[image]

I am a beginner at this and have no idea what is going wrong. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install hardhat first. cd to your projects folder and run `npm i hardhat`